# Isi it possible in c++ to have a terminal inside a window

Tags: c++, windows, shell

I have a text editor application and I wanted to try to add a shell, something like vscode.
I'm creating the window using sfml.

I don't have no clue of how to do this...
My idea was to executing shell commands, without showing cmd window, and put the result inside a file and read it, but it's not possible to do that because the cmd will show up for a bit.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using vbs script, for example, save the code below in a vbs file and replace the address of the bat file you want to execute with the value of "file address".

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "file address.bat", 0, True
```

or by using the "CreateProcess" method in C++ and with the "CREATE_NO_WINDOW" flag
You can do this
for example:

```
 CreateProcess(NULL, lpszCommandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
          CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &s, &p);
```

and for more info you can use:
[link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes)
[link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa)

Comment: unlikely the createprocess method actually show up a cmd window, i'll try with vbs

Comment: check this flag in createproccess "STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW"

Comment: .vbs works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this from C++ is almost certainly to use `popen` (or `_popen`, if you're using VC++).

This will execute the child (not in a visible window), and return a `FILE *` that you can read with normal C file functions (getchar, fgets, fscanf, etc.), but what you read isn't coming from a normal file--rather, it's the output of the child program. When you reach the "end of file", it means the child had quit executing, so it won't produce any more output.

Comment: I'm gonna try this. Thanks